# Combination of two columns unique constraint

Tags: sqlite, constraints, unique-constraint

I created the table *t1t2* which connects tables *t1* and *t2* as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE t1t2(
id integer primary key,
t1_id integer,
t2_id integer,
foreign key(t1_id) references t1(id),
foreign key(t2_id) references t2(id));
```

Is it possible to define a constraint (restriction) that enables only unique values of tuple (t1_id, t2_id)? Or should I check this in the application?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
 CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_twocols ON t1t2(t1_id, t2_id)
```

You will probably need to add NOT NULL to the declarations for each of the two columns.

Alternatively, you could choose to forego the primary key column (if all you're using it for is uniqueness) and create the primary key on the combination of `t1_id` and `t2_id`:

```
CREATE TABLE t1t2(
t1_id integer NOT NULL,
t2_id integer NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (t1_id, t2_id),
foreign key(t1_id) references t1(id),
foreign key(t2_id) references t2(id));
```

The PRIMARY KEY is a special case of a UNIQUE index.  Using the composite PRIMARY KEY saves you one column and one index, but requires your application to know both `t1_id` and `t2_id` to retrieve a single row from the table.

Comment: It's not only for uniqueness (I need the t1t2.id column), but I'm interested in the alternative method. Could you show the table? I will wait some time before accepting to have certainty that this is correct, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You can add a unique constraint to your create table statement.
This does not have to be the primary key.

```
UNIQUE(t1_id, t2_id),
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create your UNIQUE primary index with those options to keep your primary key and a unique constraint [SQL Lite New Index option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6Rcx.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.